# Formatting numpy float values

Tags: python, numpy, number-formatting

what is the easiest way to format a numpy float64 value like this:

```
8.928571429999999509e+02
```

to:

```
892.857
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom function:

```
>>> myformat = lambda x: "%.3f" % x
>>> myformat(8.928571429999999509e+02)
'892.857'
```

Answer (score 3):

The *natural* way should be [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

**Example**

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
>>> print np.array([8.928571429999999509e+02])
[ 892.857]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatters
"%.3f" % 8.928571429999999509e+02